# How to remove excess spaces in-between words in dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas

The index of my df are strings of company names. Eg `Wells   Fargo`

Sometimes there are excess spaces in-between the words I want to convert to only single spaces.
I tried the below but got errors.

```
**TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

df.index=re.sub(' +', ' ', df.index.astype('str').str.strip())


**AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'**

df.index=df.index.astype('str').str.strip().apply(lambda x: re.sub(' +', ' ', x))
```

**Input df**

```
                  | Revenue |
Wells   Fargo     | 1       |
  Bank of American| 3       |
```

**Desired output**

```
                | Revenue |
Wells Fargo     | 1       |
Bank of American| 3       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str.split() on string and then df.rename on index. See each step below.

```
import pandas as pd 

# making your df 
d = {'index':['Wells     Fargo'], 'col1':[123], 'col2':[123]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index('index')

# get list of index strings
index_str_list = [strings for strings in df.index]

# format spaces and append to new list 
new_list = []
for i in index_str_list:
    s1,s2 = i.split()
    s = "{:6}{:}".format(s1,s2) # set your distance 
    new_list.append(s)

# change index value
for old,new in zip(index_str_list, new_list):
    df.rename(index={old:new}, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

```
Output:
             col1  col2
index                  
Wells Fargo   123   123
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

In your first attempt, you are trying to pass a Pandas Index of strings to `re.sub`, which takes a string.

`apply` would work if the company names were stored as a data frame column. However as the error message says, `apply` is not implemented for the index.